# Question about Hybrid Monte Carlo

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo

In a Hamiltonian system, the Hamiltonian is always preserved, but in HMC algorithm, new state is accepted by probability $\min(1,\frac{\exp(-H_{new})}{\exp(-H)})$, I think increase or decrease in Hamiltonian is due to numerical error, why should we always prefer a state with low Hamiltonian while what we actually want is low potential energy?

Comment: Okay, I got it, transitions satisfy detailed balance.

Comment: Hi Urukec. You are encouraged to answer your own question. This website is not just for getting immediate help but is also intended to be an encyclopedic record for people who may encounter the same problem sometime in the future.